# Issue with building ionic app for release (XCode)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an older app for a client that is created with Ionic and Cordova.
I had to update the project, but when I try to make the app run on an ios device the process fails.
I open the project in XCode and try to run it on a Simulator. The text indicates the app is added to the simulator and is running, but no Simulator is popping up.

I tried to run it on my own device (iPhone 12), but then I receive an error message:
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Anyone has an idea of what I can try?

Comment: usually exit with a nonzero error is available to things like pods... the first thing you should solve is the simulator to open... if it didn't run then maybe u need to go to the latest xcode version which is maybe 13 or 14... then if it simulator works but app still gives an error then u should update the pods... and can't talk much since its wide topic for now... need to know if u have tested the things i mentioned...

Comment: next codeSIgn failed maybe be since u have invalid ios distribution certificate... so in such case it will onlt work for simulator but not on normal device untill u provide correct distribution certification... finally if u already have distribution data and everything is okay, then perhaps try locking then unlocking ur keychains then give it a test,,,